# JavaScript file(jQuery steps) not loading in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am using a jQuery plugin the file name is jquery.steps.js.

I include it in index.html unambiguously but Chrome will not load this script. It was somehow in the cache earlier which is why I never noticed this.

Can anyone suggest what the problem might be and how in the world I can get it to load.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Add what your current code for the html `<head>` is, then I can help.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure why you are getting that problem but you could solve it adding

`'?whateverHere'`

at the end of your src attribute of the script, that will enforce the script to be loaded again.